# When the scene is loaded again start function is not getting called from the script in which I have applied singleton pattern

Tags: unity

In `Game` scene I have an empty `GameObject` Circles to which a script named Circles is attached.
The script is:

```
public class Circles : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text text;
    LevelManager levelManager;
   public int score=0;
    int enemyNo;
  private void Awake()
    {
        int scorer = FindObjectsOfType<Circles>().Length;
        if (scorer > 1)
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
      
    }
 void Start()
    {
        
        print("start");
        enemyNo = Random.Range(0, 4);
        Invoke("instantiator", 1.5f);
      
        text.text = score.ToString();
        levelManager = FindObjectOfType<LevelManager>();
        
    }
}
```

When the player loses he goes to `GameOver` scene where his score is displayed.
When the player presses play again button then he comes to `Game` scene again and the start function is not getting called.
When the player presses the play again button I want to destroy previously existing Circles `GameObject` and not the `GameObject` Circles which is present in the scene so that score is set to zero and the start function get called.
How to fix this issue?

Comment: The whole point of a singleton (or part of the point at least), is that it persists between scenes. That is what your `DontDestroyOnLoad` does. So start will only be called once, as intended.

Comment: @Majs I am using `DontDestroyOnLoad` so that I can access the score variable in the  next scene that is `GameOver` scene and then I want to destroy Circles `GameObject` because then I have no use of that.

Comment: You are missing some pretty important concepts in the singleton pattern. Ur solution might work but its not good. Take a look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGGg9ecy0K4

Answer (score 3):

i have figured out the solution for this question.
In the Circles script which is provided in the question I have added these lines of code:-

```
 void OnEnable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    private void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        // here you can use scene.buildIndex or scene.name to check which scene was loaded
        if (scene.name == "GameOver")
        {
            
            // Destroy the gameobject this script is attached to
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

And everything is working just as I wanted.

Comment: Yes that would work and your previous version did not because if you use DontDestroyOnLoad obviously the Start will only be called once when the object is created and never again. Changing scenes will not trigger Start because that’s not what Start is meant to do.